# Unable to copy files from pscp to ubuntu - persmission denied

Tags: django, ubuntu, pscp

I am a newbie in Linux administration. I deleted my Django project directory from the remote Ubuntu server. The project was located here:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/my_proj
```

So I removed my_proj doing `rm -rf my_proj`, and then I re-created my_proj doing

`sudo mkdir my_proj`.

Then I go back to my local Windows putty app, and run the following command:

```
pscp -r C:\Users\workspace\my_proj my_username@remove_server_url:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/my_proj
```

I get `permission denied to create folder error` for every file and directory inside my_proj. I tried to run chmod command in Ubuntu, something like

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/my_proj/
```

...but get strange error:

```
sudo /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set
```

Answer (score 0):

the ownership on sudo must have mistakenly been changed. to fix login as root and run:

```
chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo && chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo
```